# Duplicate Record returning to Vf page

Tags: controller, salesforce, visualforce, apex

I am adding records into list based few criterias and returning to vf page to show in pageblock table.
But I am getting the duplicate records for each selection of picklist. let me know how to avoid this.

```
List<order__c> testlist = new List<order__c>();
for(order__c ord : testlist){
    if(selectedreports =='Booked Order MTD' && ord.order_booked_month__c==currentmonth ){
        testlist.add(ord );
    }
    if((selectedreports =='Booked Order QTD') && (ord.order_booked_quater__c=='Q1') && (Q1.Contains(currentmonth))){
        testlist.add(ord);
    }
}
return testlist;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to avoid duplicates you can use Set instead List:

```
Set<order__c> testlist = new Set<order__c>();
```

And if you need to return exactly List of items you can convert set to list in last line:

```
return new List<order__c>(testlist);
```